# clearsOnBeginEditing crash on fast switch

Tags: ios, swift

I have two UITextField with `clearsOnBeginEditing = true`.

When I fast switch between the two (type some text in one and fast switch to the other one where I also start typing in this one), at some point, they stop clearing (just like if `clearsOnBeginEditing` wasn't set). To get rid of this issue, I had to add for each field:

```
// Had weird glitch with clearsOnBeginEditing
@IBAction func totalTextFieldDidBegin(sender: AnyObject) {
    totalTextField.text = nil
}
```

Anybody has an idea what could cause this to happen? My bet would be that `clearsOnBeginEditing` do more checking and get stuck in a race condition or something, where `totalTextFieldDidBegin` action is always triggered.

I also have `Editing Changed` event, where I calculate some stuff, and then update my two UITextfields `text` value.

Comment: Switching fast between them how? And what other delegate methods do you have implemented? Does it change the text at all? This is probably going to need debugging as an answer would probably be guesswork at this point in time.

Comment: @Wain I updated my question, I hope it's a bit clearer, thanks.